# converting linq result to dictionary<string, int>

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I'm quite new to csharp and linq, so am having some trouble with a simple enough casting issue.

I have a simple object  -

```
public class AskQuestionFormView
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,int> Location { get; set; }
}
```

and a linq query

```
  AskQuestionFormView aqfv = new AskQuestionFormView();
        var result = from c in db.Countries
                   .ToDictionary(c => c.LocationName.ToString(),
                                    c=>c.ID)
                   select c;
        aqfv.Location = (Dictionary<string,int>)result;
```

but I'm getting the following error -

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Int32],System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]'.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is attempting to query from the dictionary, which is returning a `KeyValuePair` when you use `select c`. You just need to generate a `Dictionary` from the table, so try this instead:

```
var result = db.Countries.ToDictionary(c => c.LocationName, c => c.ID);
aqfv.Location = result;
```

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
    var result = (from c in db.Countries
                 select c).ToDictionary(c => c.LocationName.ToString(),
                                c=>c.ID);
    aqfv.Location = result;
```